# Characterizing territory according to its relief using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, spatial-analyst, geography

I want to characterize the territory according to its relief with ArcGis 10. I'm trying to define a wide territory by its relief, but I would like to do it in an automatic or semiautomatic form with the GIS.

I read on some webs that I can do it with the topographic position index, but I don't know how. Can somebody explain or give some references to learn how I can do this analysis?

Comment: Is it a single wide territory or are there zones involved that you wish to characterize? Is topographic position the the relief characteristic you are most interested in? I don't know if I can answer that part for you.

Comment: Here is a very helpful blog relating to your question: http://gis4geomorphology.com/roughness-topographic-position/

Comment: Thanks jbchurchill and Aaron for answering. Yes, I think topographic position is what I want. I read on internet that with Grass GIS I can do it with the extension r. geomorphon, to identify geomorphic spaces. I would like to know if there is any possibility to do the same thing with ArcGIS 10.